# How to extend my root and home partitions when boot is in the way?

Tags: boot, partitioning, filesystem, swap

I installed Docker but found that it used up a lot of my root partition and got a warning about it being full. When I opened gparted, I found out that I have this big chunk of unallocated space at the end of my drive that I had somehow overlooked. When I try to extend the root or home partitions, both my swap and boot partitions are in the way. How would I re-partition my drive so that boot and swap are out of the way and both root and home are able to extend into my free space?

[image: A screenshot of my gparted]

Comment: do you have a LiveCD? manipulating mounted partitions is dangerous

Comment: Do you *need* separate / and /home partitions?

Comment: Typically the ESP - efi system partition as sda1 is first partition from left. You now have unallocated in that space. I then make swap last partition or all the way to the right in gparted. Whatever you do make sure you have good backups. If you delete swap and recreate it, you have to also update fstab with new UUID, Same with ESP, but then have to totally reinstall grub. Those would be easiest way to then allow moving partitions.

Comment: @user535733 Nope, but for some reason I thought I would when I first partitioned my drive...

Answer (score 1):

I would actually create a *new* partition in the unallocated space and mount that (at boot via `/etc/fstab`) at a convenient location. What's convenient for you depends on your use case.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow symbolically link the new partition to my root or home partitions? Like, make it so that it acts as root despite being on the other side of the drive?

Comment: @TomKo: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you want or [open a new question](/questions/ask) about that and notify me of it? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion.

Answer (score 0):

One **easy** alternative, since this is not a dual-boot system, is a clean reinstall.

Backup your data first to some other media - repartitioning always risks *complete data loss*.

Choose the installer defaults (use whole disk).

It's a bit heavier of a hammer than is actually needed to solve a simple partitioning problem, and a full backup-and-reinstall takes an hour or so...but for unskilled users who have rather boxed themselves in, this will also wipe away other inevitable and best-forgotten mistakes.

Serious reminder: Back up your data to some other media first or you will surely lose it all.